# TabbedPage don't always display tab's labels after more than 3 tabs used

Tags: android, xamarin, shift, tabbedpage

I got this for my navigation:

```
     <TabbedPage ....

       <TabbedPage.Children>
            <NavigationPage Title=" MY_TITLE_1 ">
                <NavigationPage.Icon>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="icon1.png" />
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="icon1.png" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </NavigationPage.Icon>
            </NavigationPage>
            <NavigationPage Title=" MY_TITLE_2 ">
   ....
     </TabbedPage>
```

The problem is that , when I put 4 or 5 tabs my text is hidden , and I need to click on the tab in order to see the text ( in other words I see only the text of the tab that is clicked ).

In iOS the text is always visible.
Is there any way to make it in Android too?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED: This article did the trick for me. The solution was to turn off shifting.

https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-fully-customize-bottom-tabs-on-android-turn-off-shifting/

In summary, I updated

> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils,
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, 
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Design,
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4,
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCombat,
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.7.cardView,
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter

I made this file in Android solution:

```
  using Android.Support.Design.BottomNavigation;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using App16.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly:ResolutionGroupName ("MyCompany")]
[assembly:ExportEffect (typeof(NoShiftEffect), "NoShiftEffect")]
namespace App16.Droid
{
    public class NoShiftEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached ()
        {
            if (!(Container.GetChildAt(0) is ViewGroup layout))
                return;

            if (!(layout.GetChildAt(1) is BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView))
                return;

            // This is what we set to adjust if the shifting happens
            bottomNavigationView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityLabeled;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In the shared solution :

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App16
{
    public class NoShiftEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public NoShiftEffect() : base("MyCompany.NoShiftEffect")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and this in my XAML:

```
<TabbedPage.Effects>
    <local:NoShiftEffect />
</TabbedPage.Effects>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24897959)

Comment: You are right! That's why I wrote "The solution was to turn off shifting"

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the provided page inside your answer. This way other people have access to the conplete solution, even if the url gets broken